# Issue creating MTLBuffer from MTLTexture used as inputs in CoreML Custom Layer for GPU execution

Tags: metal, coreml, metalkit, coremltools, mtlbuffer

I am trying to create a CoreML Custom layer that runs on the GPU, using Objective-C for CoreML setup and Metal for GPU programming.

I have created the CoreML model with the custom layer and can successfully execute on the GPU, I wish to create an MTLBuffer from an input MTLTexture in my setup actual GPU execution, although I can't seem to do so, or get access to the memory address to the MTLTexture memory.

When defining a custom layer in CoreML to run on the GPU, the following function needs to be defined, with the given prototype;

```
(BOOL) encodeToCommandBuffer:(id<MTLCommandBuffer>)commandBuffer inputs:(NSArray<id<MTLTexture>> *)inputs outputs:(NSArray<id<MTLTexture>> *)outputs error:(NSError *__autoreleasing  _Nullable *)error{

    // GPU Setup, moving data, encoding, execution and so on here

}
```

Here, the `inputs` are passed as an NSArray of MTLTexture's, we then pass these texture's on to the Metal Shader for computation. My problem is that I want to pass an MTLBuffer to the Metal Shader, which points to the input data, say `inputs[0]`, but I am having troubling copying the input MTLTexture to an MTLBuffer.

I have tried using the `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to copy the data from the MTLTexture to an MTLBuffer like so;

```
id<MTLBuffer> test_buffer = [command_PSO.device newBufferWithLength:(8) options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared];
id <MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitCommandEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];
[blitCommandEncoder copyFromTexture:inputs[0]
                            sourceSlice:0
                            sourceLevel:0
                           sourceOrigin:MTLOriginMake(0, 0, 0)
                             sourceSize:MTLSizeMake(1, 1, 1)
                               toBuffer:test_buffer
                      destinationOffset:0
                 destinationBytesPerRow:8
               destinationBytesPerImage:8];
[blitCommandEncoder endEncoding];
```

The above example *should* copy a single pixel from the MTLTexture, `inputs[0]`, to the MTLBuffer, `test_buffer`, but this is not the case.

MTLTextures, `getBytes` also doesn't work as the inputs have `MTLResourceStorageModePrivate` set.

When I inspect the input MTLTexture I note that the attribute `buffer = <null>` and I'm wondering if this could be an issue since the texture was not created from a buffer, and perhaps doesn't store the address to memory easily, but surely we should be able to get the memory address somewhere?

For further reference, here is the input MTLTexture definition;

```
<CaptureMTLTexture: 0x282469500> -> <AGXA14FamilyTexture: 0x133d9bb00>
    label = <none> 
    textureType = MTLTextureType2DArray 
    pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Float 
    width = 8 
    height = 1 
    depth = 1 
    arrayLength = 1 
    mipmapLevelCount = 1 
    sampleCount = 1 
    cpuCacheMode = MTLCPUCacheModeDefaultCache 
    storageMode = MTLStorageModePrivate 
    hazardTrackingMode = MTLHazardTrackingModeTracked 
    resourceOptions = MTLResourceCPUCacheModeDefaultCache MTLResourceStorageModePrivate MTLResourceHazardTrackingModeTracked  
    usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite 
    shareable = 0 
    framebufferOnly = 0 
    purgeableState = MTLPurgeableStateNonVolatile 
    swizzle = [MTLTextureSwizzleRed, MTLTextureSwizzleGreen, MTLTextureSwizzleBlue, MTLTextureSwizzleAlpha] 
    isCompressed = 0 
    parentTexture = <null> 
    parentRelativeLevel = 0 
    parentRelativeSlice = 0 
    buffer = <null> 
    bufferOffset = 0 
    bufferBytesPerRow = 0 
    iosurface = 0x0 
    iosurfacePlane = 0 
    allowGPUOptimizedContents = YES
    label = <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, `destinationBytesPerRow` and `destinationBytesPerImage` are calculated incorrectly. Referring to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder/1400773-copyfromtexture?language=objc)

> destinationBytesPerRow
> The stride in bytes between rows of the source texture memory. The value must be a multiple of the source texture's pixel size, in bytes. The value must be less than or equal to 32,767 multiplied by the source texture’s pixel size.

> destinationBytesPerImage
> For 3D textures and 2D array textures, the stride in bytes between 2D images of the source buffer memory. The value must be a multiple of the source texture's pixel size, in bytes.

Your texture is 8 pixels wide and has `.rgba16Float` format, so `destinationBytesPerRow` should be 8 * 8. Same for `destinationBytesPerImage`, it seems like it should be 64 in your case.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, correct, the texture in this case is 8 pixels, but, I am only trying to copy a single pixel (the first one) into the buffer to verify it works correctly, I assume this is achievable and we don't have to copy the entire texture.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't copy the entire texture, but it still needs you to calculate the right `bytesPerRow` and `perImage`.

Comment: Actually, I might be wrong.

Comment: By the way, `-[MTLTexture buffer]` property is `nil` cause your texture is created from an `MTLDevice` and not an `MTLBuffer`, so it's okay. If you are gonna be using this texture just to copy it to `MTLBuffer` anyway you can try allocating it from a buffer instead, so you can deal with it as a buffer.

Comment: Another thing you can try is capturing it with Frame Capture in Xcode and see if the app is doing what you think it should be doing.

Comment: Thanks again @JustSomeGuy, unfortunately it seems the allocation is handled by CoreML and we can only access the texture through `inputs` to the `encodeToCommandBuffer` function, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlcustomlayer/2936859-encodetocommandbuffer?language=objc, unless you know some way of explicitly dealing with this allocation in CoreML? I will also take a look at the Frame Capture to inspect the behaviour, thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure how it's handled by CoreML if you are passing your textures as `inputs` and `outputs`. You should be able to allocate any texture you want.